# How to optimise repeated C function call where most args don't change

Tags: c

We have a function that will be called many 1000s of times. Between each invocation most of the arguments won't change, and we know in advance which will/won't change.

I'm wondering if there is a pattern in C that allows the compiler to optimise and avoid repeated calculations involving the unchanging args. It's somewhat related to closures. The pattern in Javascript would be expressed as:

```
function factory(s1, s2, s3) {
  return function(dyn1) {
    // first part of this can be pre-calculated
    return (s1 * s1 + s2 / s3 - s1 / s3) * dyn1;
  }
}

const fn=factory(5, 7, 9);
for ( let n=0; n< 100000; n++ ) {
  const r=fn(n);
}
```

Note: I am not claiming that a Javascript interpreter will optimise this, but hopefully the above demonstrates the scenario and potential for optimisation.

In practice we have 100's of equations each with complex maths expressions involving 10+ vars and 20+ operations. To optimise by hand would be painful!

Interested to know if there is a good way to approach this.

Thanks

Comment: C or Javascript? The code you posted isn't C, yet you mention C in the title and tagged it with C.

Comment: @AndrewHenle The code is an example (in Javascript) of the functionality the OP is describing, and wants to achieve in C. There's nothing wrong with that, I would hope.

Comment: Not in the form you describe, c does not have lamdba function like c++, although gcc does have nested functionality, I do not think it would work like you desire.

Comment: Are the values of the unchanging parameters known at compile time (as in your example), or are they runtime values?

Comment: Why dont you do the calculations the 1st time, save those results if you know in advanced you are going to use them, and instead of calculate again. It is similar to fibonacci recursive somehow

Comment: @Angew, the unchanging parameters are not known at compile time. In our case they are parameters for a numeric solve.

Comment: @dvhh, I am looking at nested functions in gcc but you are not supposed to return a nested function

Comment: @M.K that is a possibility but we are using many, many complex equations generated by Mathematica and to optimise by hand would be a big, error prone job

Comment: @jugglingcats: If these equations are on the reals (and you plan on using floating point math in C to approximate them); and since you are on Mathematica (which you can script); I would suggest optimizing them (fold the known constants and get the simplest exact representation) in Mathematica itself and then copying the resulting optimized (but *exact*) equations. Even more, it should be possible to get Mathematica to numerically approximate all the constants to a precision better than that `double` before copying them to the C code. [...]

Comment: [...] Even then, be very careful with the results; specially if you are aiming for performance and end up enabling "unsafe" floating point optimizations -- dealing with different optimizer decisions for different versions of the software when dealing with floating point issues can quickly become a nightmare. Aim to keep a pretty good battery of tests with known good results up to some defined precision you care about (possibly automatically generated from Mathematica).

Comment: @Acorn, you comments are helpful thanks. I was starting to think along these lines where we take the Mathematica equations and replace parts of equations with values that can be pre-calculated (but still pre-calculated at runtime). You mention "fold the known constants". Is there a function for this in Mathematica? I might post a question there...!

Comment: @jugglingcats: I am no expert on Mathematica, but applying `FullSimplify` after providing Mathematica with the proper constants/substitutions/assumptions should work. Then, for numeric approximations up to some precision, you can use `N`. There is also the topic about formulating the results as numerically stable expressions (for floating point math), etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the `pure` and `const` attributes in GCC (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes). Also, I would check `__builtin_constant_p` in https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html.

Some of these attributes can be suggested by GCC using `-Wsuggest-attribute` warning.

Take care because if you mark a function with that attributes, the compiler will assume that behavior and will not make questions: for example, if you say that a function is pure and it is not, the return value for given parameters will be reused no matter if the function is pure or not!

Also, note that some of these optimizations will be done by the compiler even if you don't set that functions pure/const. The only way to truly know that compiler optimizations are, as far as I know, to look in the generated assembler.

AS a side note, you can also check if you can apply -ffast-math, but be careful because the code behaves very differently. See https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FloatingPointMath

Comment: In most cases there is no need to use those non-standard attributes, since compilers can typically prove whether a function is pure/const. Normally, they are only used for cases where the compiler cannot prove it themselves (and the performance is critical).

Comment: The key is *in most cases*. For example, if you do not enable lto, and function definition and usage are in different files, it can't be applied. Same if they are in a shared library. Putting these attributes in the function declaration can save you a few ops. As always, benchmark before apply performance changes!

Comment: If you are in a situation where marking functions pure/const is noticeable in your measurements, but you are not allowing IPOs, then you are already losing much more performance just by that. Instead of working on marking functions manually, start spending time on enabling LTO or unity builds, and you will gain more performance and avoid the extra work and maintenance burden of marking functions manually.

Comment: I agree with that point but, following that lead, we are getting farther from the original question, IMHO. There is a lot of circumstances that can't be solved with lto (shared libraries, for example), and we don't know what is the asker situation beyond that he wants to signal the compiler that the function is const/pure, overriding the better or worse guessing the compiler can do.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I agree that marking functions pure/const can help the optimizer a lot in a case like this (specially if the equations OP refers to are functions calling all one another). However, since OP is specifically mentioning that the concern is optimizations regarding calling the functions with a set of known parameters at compile-time, it seems that pureness is not the big deal here -- but rather folding the constants and inlining.

Comment: Actually, your comment regarding the floating point math can be a big deal here -- since OP is talking about Mathematica in the comments of the question, there is a good chance the equations are indeed using reals. Thanks, I commented a bit on that there as well.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm wondering if there is a pattern in C that allows the compiler to optimise and avoid repeated calculations involving the unchanging args.

In general, you do not need to change your code nor write anything special to achieve good performance in these cases. The reason is that optimizing compilers (including popular compilers for C) will perform [Common Subexpression Elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_subexpression_elimination) (CSE), [inlining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion), [constant propagation and folding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding), [hoisting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-invariant_code_motion) and other optimizations that are critical to achieve good performance for this typical scenario.

In particular, calling a function with constant arguments is something that any reasonably good optimizer will handle just fine. They will also factor out of a loop whatever they can prove does not change between iterations.

Of course, the compiler needs to have all the require information available (e.g. in the same translation unit or by taking advantage of [WPO/LTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interprocedural_optimization)) and you need to avoid anything that prevents optimizations to take place.

In general, try to keep your code as simple as possible and take a look at the assembly or intermediate outputs of your compiler to be sure that things were able to be optimized properly.

If, nevertheless, you notice that your compiler is not being able to optimize what you would expect it should be able to, analyze why and try to remove whatever is preventing the optimization. In the worst case, you will have to change your code to do it yourself; but don't embark on a quest of reorganizing your code without proper information beforehand. This is similar as the general principle as avoiding optimizations without profiling first.

Answer (score 1):

The normal C way would be to split the dynamic and static part:

```
int f1(int s1, int s2, int s3) {
    return (s1 * s1 + s2 / s3 - s1 / s3);
}

int f2(int s, int dyn) {
    return s * dyn;
}

int s = f1(5, 7, 9);
for(int n=0; n<100000; n++) {
    int r = f2(s, n);
    ...
}
```

If you have to do same operations on multiple functions, meta-programming through macros may come handy.